# linear algebra homogeneous system

Tags: linear-algebra

True of false, explain

If the homogeneous system A⃗x = ⃗0 has only the trivial solution, then the corresponding non- homogeneous A⃗x = ⃗b has a unique solution for each ⃗b.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: See how is obtained the echelon matrix in this [Example 2](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~stecher/Linear-Algebra/Systems/examples.html).

By application of the so called **Gauss–Jordan elimination**. On assumption that your homogeneus system has a unique solution, ask you what is the shape of the matrix that you have obtained (it is the same that the example) and if has relevance what vector $b$ you've used in the augmented matrix.

I say that $b$ has its importance when we are solving a system or other different, but with respect your question, the unicity of solutions, you need do your trials, first with the$b$ of the example, and after with the zero vector computing the solution in both cases.

Then with respect your proof you need see this obvious proof is your classroom notes or in a book.

Comment: if the system has only the trivial solution, doesn't mean that there will be a pivot position in every column? then does it really matter what b is since there is always a solution?

Comment: Today I forgot linear algebra, but in the dictionary of my brain say: system with a unique solution iff its associated matrix is (square) the identity, thus has no relevance (for your question that is the unicity of a system of $n\times n$) the attached $b$ that you take in RHS of you augmented matrix; only has relevance that you do good computations with this $b$, modifying this following your elimination method @Jayden I hope that other user provide to you a better explanation/example (or an obvious proof). You need convince to you with examples and after read the proof in your book.

Comment: The elimination method transform your matrix of coefficients in an identity (by assumption that your homogeneous system has a unique solution) then the non homogeneous system has a matrix that yet is the identity @Jayden