# If a homogeneous system has only the trivial solution, is $Ax = b$ consistent?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, homogeneous-equation

True or False?

If the homogeneous system $Ax = 0$ has only the trivial solution, then the corresponding non-homogeneous Ax = b is consistent for each b.

My answer is: False.
Since all homogeneous systems are consistent, that $Ax = 0$ has only the trivial solution only says that the Matrix $A$ has the form $m\times n$ where $m\ge n.$
However, it is not sufficient to say if $Ax = b$ is consistent for each $b$, since a counter-example would be:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
5x &+& 3y &=& 1\\
5x &+& 2y &=& 1\\
5x &+& y &=& 1
\end{eqnarray}
$$
True or False?

Comment: What do you mean by "consistent"?

Comment: that the linear system has a solution

Comment: But the given example has the solution (x = 1/5, y = 0), right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [linear algebra homogeneous system](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1809342/linear-algebra-homogeneous-system)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is right, but the explanation is not entirely accurate.

First, note that saying $A x = 0$ has only the trivial solution is actually equivalent to saying that the nullspace of $A$ only contains the null vector or, still equivalently, the columns of $A$ are linearly independent.

Now, the equation $A x = b $ can only have a solution if $b$ is in the column space of $A$. So, as you pointed out, even when the columns of $A$ are linearly independent, still $A x = b $ may have no solution. If $A$ is square, though, then of course $A x = b $ always has a solution when its columns are linearly independent, since then its columns span the whole space.

(This does not apply to your example, though, since $(1,1,1)$ is clearly in the column space of $A$.)

Comment: Can you give a good counter example then?